# In javascript, using requireJS, how do I "require" a typescript object?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

In my javascript file I have:

```js
require(["menu/main-menu"], function (mainMenu) {
```

where main-menu is built from main-menu.ts. javascript/requireJS wants me to build up a define I return in main-menu. But typescript doesn't do that AFAIK.

How can I accomplish this?

**Update:** For example, the following tells me the export keyword is incorrect:

```
///<reference path='../../libs/ExtJS-4.2.0.d.ts' />
///<reference path='../../libs/require.d.ts' />

import fdm = require("./file-definitions");
require(["../../scripts/ribbon"], function () {

export module Menu {

    export class MainMenu {
    }
}
```

Comment: "import" is for external modules.  Once you use it, the file should be compiled into an external (i.e. RequireJS or CommonJS) module.  "module" is for internal modules.  I don't think you can export an internal module from an external module.  In addition, you need to use the "export =" syntax for RequireJS modules because TypeScript defaults to CommonJS-style modules.

Comment: In other words, something like: import fdm = require("./file-definitions"); import ribbon = require("../../scripts/ribbon"); class MainMenu { ... }  export = MainMenu;

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to access `MainMenu` in JavaScript using RequireJS? Then your JavaScript should look like:

```js
require(["path/to/MainMenu"],function(mainMenu){
    mainMenu.doSomething();
});
```

Now, assuming you are using TypeScript `0.9.1` or later, you can assign a value to the exported value of your module. So you could write your MainMenu.ts file like this:

```
class MainMenu {
    doSomething(): void {
    }
}
export = MainMenu;
```

---

**Edit**: You are using the export statement inside of a `function` which is not allowed. If your code relies on the ribbon script being included, I suggest you require it with an import statement as well. So:

```
import ribbon = require("../../scripts/ribbon");
```

Now, if this is an external script and you haven't written it in TypeScript yourself, you need to tell the compiler this module exists. In your declaration file add the following:

```
declare module "../../scripts/ribbon" {};
```

A declaration file is a TypeScript file with the extension `*.d.ts`. It contains only declarations, not implementations. You could compare it to a C header file. For example, you can download a declaration file for jQuery. This will give you the TypeScript compiler support for jQuery without actually needing a TypeScript version of jQuery.

The same principle can be used here, for the `ribbon` file. If you don't already have a declaration file, simply add one to your project, for example: `declarations.d.ts`. If you are using Visual Studio as your editor, normally the TypeScript plugin should automatically pick up this declaration file. You can check if the file is correctly picked up in case the import statement for ribbon above does not throw an error. In case this does not work, simply add a reference statement in `MainMenu.ts`:

```
///<reference path='../../libs/declarations.d.ts' />
```

Provided you have created the declarations.d.ts file under the same lib as the other declaration files you were already referencing.

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work (see the update with my specific code listed). Is there anything else? Thanks - dave

Comment: I still get an error on the export in "export module Menu". How can I avoid that? thanks - dave

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.9.1.1 which I believe is the latest.

Comment: I'm using version 0.9.1.1 which I believe is the latest.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, ribbon is not a .ts file, it's a .js file. Does define still work for that. And what is a declaration file? Thanks

Comment: Hi;  I created ribbon.d.ts and added <reference path='../../libs/ribbon.d.ts' />. Is that sufficient to have it load ribbon.js? Or do I need to explicitly request it? I tried "import rib = require("../../scripts/ribbon");" but I get an error on it. I also get the error if I do import rib = require("../../scripts/ribbon.js"); ??? - thanks - dave

Comment: David, no you need to import it, but I noticed I made a mistake in my example code, please review and make sure the declaration file contains the following snippet `declare module "../../scripts/ribbon" {};` Now the import statement `import rib = require("../../scripts/ribbon");` should no longer throw an error. Can you verify this?

Answer (score 0):

To do a manual require (e.g. for a lazy load) with a callback you can use the RequireJS definitions for TypeScript from DefinitelyTyped : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/requirejs

Comment: How do I set up a manual require? I tried require(...) and can't find a way that works.

Comment: Exactly the same as you would do in javascript

Comment: I tried that, still doesn't work (see the update above with my specific code listed). Is there anything else? Thanks - dave